# MVC 5 Cannot get RenderPage or RenderPartial to Work Properly

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6, asp.net-mvc-5

There are lots of questions and answers concerning this topic, but I am not having any luck getting this to work.

I have two views.  One represents a parent, the other is child records.  Everything is read only so the views are very simple.

Here is my parent view:

```
@model IEnumerable<WebApplication1.vw_CurrentDump>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "CurrentDump";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_MyLayout.cshtml";
}
@section head{
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/css/style.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" } />
}
<style>
    .headerTest {
        text-align: center;
        width: 100%;
    }
</style>

<h2 class="headerTest">Current Dump</h2>

<table class="aTable">
    <tr>
        <th>
            Dump #
        </th>
        <th>
            Units
        </th>
        <th>
            Start
        </th>
        <th>
            Cars
        </th>
        <th>
            Weight
        </th>
        <th>
            Cars Dumped
        </th>
        <th>
            Tons Dumped
        </th>
        <th>
            Destination
        </th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DumpUnitId)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Units)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.StartTime)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Cars)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Weight)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CarsDumped)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TonsDumped)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Desintation)
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
@{  Html.RenderPartial("CurrentDumpCars"); }
```

Here is the view for the child records:

```
@model IEnumerable<WebApplication1.vw_CurrentDumpCars>

@{
    Layout = null;
}
<table class="aTable">
    <tr>
        <th>
            Car Number
        </th>
        <th>
            Date Dumped
        </th>
        <th>
            Weight
        </th>
        <th>
            Empty Track
        </th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CarNumber)
            </td>
            <td>
                @if (item.DateDumped.HasValue)
                {
                    @item.DateDumped.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm")
                }
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Weight)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EmptyTrackNumber)
            </td>
        </tr>
    }

</table>
```

I have tried @RenderPage and RenderPartial (as shown).  Both return the same error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[WebApplication1.vw_CurrentDump]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[WebApplication1.vw_CurrentDumpCars]'.'

It seems to be telling me that I'm passing in vw_CurrentDump to the RenderPartial method, but that doesn't make any sense.  Both views are in an Entity Framework 6 library.  Everything I read tells me this should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CurrentDumpCars` takes `@model IEnumerable<WebApplication1.vw_CurrentDumpCars>` model but your `@{  Html.RenderPartial("CurrentDumpCars"); }` you did not pass any value or correct value. if `CurrentDumpCars` has a separate action  then try `@{  Html.RenderAction("CurrentDumpCars"); }` rather than `@{  Html.RenderPartial("CurrentDumpCars"); }` or pass `IEnumerable<WebApplication1.vw_CurrentDumpCars>` model into`@{  Html.RenderPartial("CurrentDumpCars"); }`

Example :

```
@{
var items= new IEnumerable<WebApplication1.vw_CurrentDumpCars>()//your data
}

@{  Html.RenderPartial("CurrentDumpCars",items); }
```

Comment: Fantastic!  Thank you so much.  I have a lot to learn about MVC.  I've been doing WPF for way too long.  RenderAction did the trick.